# Paypal Masspay Stopped

Tags: web-applications, paypal

we have integrated Paypal MassPay API to our web app to pay our users. However, recently, Paypal decided to deactivate this option without notice and they do not want to reactivate it...Oo'. So now, our web app is broken (thank you Paypal) and we need to find a solution.

Here are our needs:

1. Allow our users to buy our products (one product at a time);
2. Send money to our users (one user at a time);
3. Integrate with PHP;
4. Accessible for a Europe based company;

What are the best APIs for our requirements?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, I just found your post because I noticed some of my tests against the Paypal Masspay API stopped working recently.  Where did you see that Paypal has deactivated this option?  Are they officially not supporting MassPay anymore?  Any link you have to this would be helpful...Thanks

Comment: MassPay is still available, but you have to ask them to get it enabled again

Comment: No,  Masspay is not available to everybody anymore. We asked several times to reactivate it and they simply refused. They deactivated masspay for us without any notice nor annoucement mainly because we are not big enough...;(... So now, we have to quickly find a solution or we will close our service...;(

@Nader There were no annoucement about that. If you are new, you have to ask them as a favor... Hope you will get lucky;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Paypal is choosing which companies can still use MassPay and which cannot. We contacted them but we did not have any further information. The best alternative is Adaptative payments:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments

Best regards.